# Create html page dynamically client side using javascript/jquery/any..if not possible how to do it server side using php/ajax/java

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, client-side, server-side

I have a page that accepts user data (3 input fields) and an image,
On click of submit button,i need to store image and 3 input fields in some variables.

Retrieve the variable data and embed in a html table and display the image below that
Need to store this dynamic html in client side

is it possible in javascript/jquery / any at client side...

If its not possible
what are the tools that are required to do it in server side using 
php/ajax/java...
how to do it also if possible
I have RAD installed,do i need anything else like sql server..

can we use something simple sql server

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Do you have any code you are already working with?

Comment: Also do you have a database or you just need them stored in variables. If you are submitting anyway id use PHP instead of javascript for the dynamic creation

Comment: I havent tried anything yet,I am checking out the possibilities before i get into it.I do not have a database and in fact i dont want to have a database,I need this client side because to make the application portable without installing something wen some one else uses..or i do not want to host in some network and use database..because the application that i am working on is portable and independent of database

Comment: Javascript it is then :P. Id create the table first but make it hidden. Add an event handle to look for the submit. Once submitted take the content from your form and insert rows within your table with the required content

Comment: yes but i need the content to be saved and user should be able to see that page when he visits later..kind of adding to index in book..

Comment: content needs to be saved as html and add it as a hyper link .so that when he revisits and clicks on hyper link its available

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into [Underscore templates](http://underscorejs.org/#template) if you need client-side dynamic HTML.